# if (function() === false){ do this}

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

i'm trying to solve this issue, i'm relatively new to javascript, so:

function termos() gives a true or false result;

probably the solution to this is simple, but can't get to it. Is it possible to do this? i wrote this code just to exemplify my doubt

```
function termos() {
  if($('.terms').is(':checked')) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

can i use

```
} else if(termos() === false) {
  alert('please agree with terms');
  return false;
}
```

This doesn't work

Comment: Even with the edit you still don't really explain what it is you actually have a problem with.

Comment: Now it's edited, please read.

Comment: You really need to format your code properly man.

Comment: You're missing a closing quote on `please agree with terms`.

Comment: A quote is missing in your code

Comment: is this valid? `else if(termos() === false){
                        alert('please agree with terms');
                    return false;
}`

Comment: If this was Jeopardy, it would be fun, but we prefer to have a question before giving answers

Comment: Are you sure you mean `$(".terms")` instead of `$("#terms")`?

Comment: @Michael is right; you're missing a quote. Pro tip: errors like this are easier to catch if you look at your browser's error console. It will usually give a syntax error ("expecting this, got that") which will help you trace the typo.

Comment: Guys, this `else if(termos() === false){` simply wont work. I would like to have a condition where i can see if termos returns false do this, if termos return true do that

Comment: if you have compilation errors in your javascript, it's hard to tell if portions of your code will work.  their suggestion of fixing your mistake first and trying to see if that works is a good one.

Comment: i have no compilation errors in mine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved my problem. Thanks to who tried to help.

```
function termos(){
        if ($('.checky3').is(':checked')){
            return 1;
        }
    }

if (termos() !== 1){
        $('.checky3').css('border','solid 1px red');
        return false;
}
```

Answer (score 20):

From what I understand you want to see if termos() returns true or false and in this case, when it returns false you want to go through a block of code.

You can use **falsy / truthy evaluations** (http://11heavens.com/falsy-and-truthy-in-javascript)

So you can just say:

```
if ( termos() ) {
  // when its true
} else {
 // when its false
}
```

Comment: + since this answers [Souza's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11456929/if-function-false-do-this#comment15122154_11456929).

Comment: else if ( termos() ){
true}else{
false} is always returning true no matter what

Comment: @Souza: are you sure `termos()` ever returns `false`? Have you tried to `console.log()` (or `alert()`) its result?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using a class to set the jQuery object, you will get conflicting results **if you have more than one item with that class**. I am assuming based on the lack of detail from your question that this might be the case.

Set the `id` of the checkbox so you can correctly select the element. Also, it is best to set the parent container so that the jQuery isn't searching the entire DOM.

Also, you can reduce your code like so:

```
function termos(){
  return $('#Agree',"#ParentContainer").is(':checked');
}


if(!termos()){
  alert('please agree with terms');
}
```